# C++ - Functions, Parameters & Pointers - Access Violation

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I've decided to learn C++ having pretty limited previous programming knowledge. I'm currently following the book *Jumping into C++* by *Alex Allain*. I've hit the chapter on pointers and as part of the practice problems I am presented with the following problem:

> 1. Write a function that prompts the user to enter his or her first name and last name, as two seperate values. This function should return both values to the caller via additional pointer (or reference) parameters that are passed to the function. Try doing this first with pointers and then with references.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>

void getDetails(char * n, char * s)
{
    std::cout << "Input name: ";
    std::cin >> *n;

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Input surname: ";
    std::cin >> *s;
}

int main()
{
    char *name = NULL;
    char *surname = NULL;

    getDetails(name, surname);

    std::cout << "Name: " << *name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Surname: " << *surname << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I keep running into an Access Violation error and I have absolutely no idea why.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Receiving input through just a pointer like that is dangerous because the user could enter more text than you have space (no space actually, in this case). You should either use methods that let you check the amount of input, or use `std::string` which is much easier and safer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you have two Problems:

1. You are not reserving memory for `name` and `surname` (That's why you get the access violation error)
2. You are reading just one character from `cin` (Because you are dereferencing a `char*` which results in a sigle char)

You can resolve both Problems by just using `std::string` instead of `char*`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to <s>MrMarley</s>Thomas Sparber's answer*, you might find some interest in the [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function as [`std::istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) breaks on a space and the user first name may contain one.

(*) Can't comment on it yet.

Comment: Do you mean me by MrMarley? I have seen many people misspelling my surname but this is the most funny one! :-) --> +1 for that

Comment: OOps ... I read the original poster's name instead of yours :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocate memory where you are going to store name and surname.
Your pointers are null pointers.

```
char *name = NULL;
char *surname = NULL;
```

So the program has undefined behaviour.

Also I think that the author means using of objects of type `std::string`

In this case the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void getDetails( std::string *n, std::string *s )
{
    std::cout << "Input name: ";
    std::cin >> *n;

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Input surname: ";
    std::cin >> *s;
}

void getDetails( std::string &n, std::string &s )
{
    std::cout << "Input name: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Input surname: ";
    std::cin >> s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;

    getDetails( &name, &surname);

    std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Surname: " << surname << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nAnd one more" << "\n";

    getDetails( name, surname);

    std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Surname: " << surname << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```